# what is the signalR USER COUNT or HUB COUNT limitations in a real world asp.net core web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

**scenario:**
im developing a web app with 5 real Time Turn Base Card games.
each game has it own Hub and IHostedService Background Service.
users play with each other throw the Hub and Background Service.

**server :**
VPS with 24GB RAM and XEON E51650 CPU and 200GB SSD. vps is on our own dedicated server.

**estimation of online users in Peak time** : 
customer recorded 10000 Online Users in a Advertising Campaign and records in a regular day is 4000.(their OLD version application)

**problem #1:** 
there are concerns about "How many Users can be handled by SignalR Hub by default"?(i mean without Scaleout solutions )
some say:

> its limited by 1000 Concurrent Connections and No limit On Idle
>   Connections

And some say:

> there is no limit at all and the only limit is Web Server
>   Configurations and Ports

I could Not find any reliable Answer.

**problem #2:** 
what is the impact of Using unique IHostedService and Hub for each Game? we are planning add 7 more games. is there any limitation for hub count or hosted service count?

**More Info:**
the 90% of operation is *broadcasting to all Other clients* and replaying to Caller. 
there are no *groups* and no *specific user* messaging

*any help/tips and links will be appreciated.*

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685350/signalr-websockets-connection-limitations-and-best-practices) will help you to get some more info

Comment: @Thangadurai i read that before, i did not find that usfull. i think after 3 years there must be some improvements. by the way, base on the link and my games type the signalR itself seems to be a good approach.