# ASP.NET SignalR - Too many connection on IIS in AuthorizeRequest state

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

I have an ASP.NET application using SignalR (2.2.1.0) in production and sometimes happens that there are more than 1000 connections in AuthorizeRequest state.
Any way to limit the number of connections? Could the Timeout setting help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set up the below property.
[image]
The `appConcurrentRequestLimit` attribute specifies the maximum number of concurrent requests that can be queued for an application.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serverruntime

Besides, please have a look at these links.
[Set limit concurrent connections for websocket on iis 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500495/set-limit-concurrent-connections-for-websocket-on-iis-8)
[SignalR / Websockets connection limitations and best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685350/signalr-websockets-connection-limitations-and-best-practices)